# AutoFixture AutoMoq adding items to an ObservableCollection does not raise CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I'm just starting out using `AutoFixture` and I'm enjoying the features just now. But I've just created an `AutoMoqDataAttribute` as Mark Seemann describes [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/).

But now I'm trying to mock an object that contains an `ObservableCollection` of items and in my `Sut` I am subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event and handling when new items are added.

My `Sut` looks like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar barWithObservableCollection)
    {
        barWithObservableCollection.Items.CollectionChanged += this.OnItemsChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IFooThing> FooThings
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void OnItemsChanged(object sender,  NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // Handle the new object and build a new IFooThing with it.
        ...
        this.FooThings.Add(fooThing);
    }
}
```

My `IBar` interface is simple and basically only contains the `ObservableCollection`:

```
public interface IBar
{
    ObservableCollection<IBarThings> Items
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

So in my original implementation of the test to make sure that new items were handled was with full mocking of the objects using `Moq` and tying everything together myself (I'll leave this out as it's unnecessary for my question). But as said I've attempted to move this to using `AutoFixture` and now my tests looks like:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestNewIBarThingsAreCorrectlyHandled([Frozen]IBar bar, [Frozen]IBarThing barThing, Foo sut)
{
    bar.Items.Add(barThing);

    Assert.Equal(1, sut.FooThings.Count);
}
```

So I was expecting that the `IBar.Items` was auto setting up an `ObservableCollection` which it is and this was being subscribed to, which it also is. But when I do the call to `bar.Items.Add` the collection changed handler is not not called, although I can see that the `Items` count is incremented on the `IBar` object.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Have I got the wrong end of the stick and I will have to manually setup the collection as before, I'd rather not have to do this as I'm enjoying the cleaner syntax?

EDIT:
After the comment below I checked that the `IBar` object provided to the tests and to the `Sut` were the same, but it turns out that these are not the same object. I was under the impression that the `[Frozen]` attribute specified that each time that object was requested the same object reference would be returned?

Comment: Are `bar` and the instance passed to the `Foo` constructor the same object\reference?

Comment: Ah that looks like what the issue is, the `IBar` (`bar` object) in the test does have the item added but the one stored within the `Foo` object does not after the `Add`. I believed that the `Frozen` attribute specified that you would have the same instance of the object on each request to the `Fixture`?

Comment: Based on the information given here, I can't get the code to compile. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).